# Angular: Binding Observable values in the template

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

**Angular 10**

In my component I have a simple Observable:

```
me$: Observable<User> = this.store.select((s) => s.user);
```

I wish to show the user.firstName, but this is blank result:

```
<div>You are {{ me$.firstName | async }}</div>
```

If I use this, it works, so I know data is coming:

```
me$ = this.store.select((s) => s.user.firstName);
```

Comment: {{ (me$ | async)?.firstName }}

Comment: Or simple remove async and check if is better

Answer (score 1):

`me$` observable should be resolved first before you call a property of the value.

```html
<div>You are {{ (me$ | async)?.firstName }}</div>
```